# Solve quadric equation system

Tags: calculus, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

#### How to solve this analytically(not a numerical solution)?

For given real and symmetric matrices
$A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4\in\mathbb{R}^{4\times4}$
find
$0\neq x\in\mathbb{R}^4$

$$x^TA_1x=0$$
$$x^TA_2x=0$$
$$x^TA_3x=0$$
$$x^TA_4x=0$$

## Example:

Solve the system:

\begin{align}
a^2+b^2+c &=3.95 \\
ab+bc+c^2 &=4.57 \\
ac+b &=2.63 \\ 
\end{align}
Denoting:
\begin{equation}
x = \begin{bmatrix}a & b & c & 1\end{bmatrix}^T
\end{equation}

Then the matrices, $A_k$ can be build from the equations, for example to form $A_1$, we rewrite the first equation in matrix form  $x^TB_1x=0$ where:
\begin{equation}
B_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&-3.95\\  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Then, since from $x^TB_1x=0$ transpose leads to $x^TB_1^Tx=0$, the sum is: 
$x^T(B_1+B_1^T)x=0$
denoting the matrix as $A_1=(B_1+B_1^T)$, it is symmetric and  $x^TA_1x=0$

Comment: What does this have to do with calculus?

Comment: Anything common for matrices $A_{1,2,3,4}$? Additional properties?

Comment: Strikes me as quite messy. No nonzero answer if any $A_i$ is definite, no guarantee of intersection of even two null cones. Why do you want to know?????????

Answer (score 1):

If you accept a numerical solution, then it is possible to make a convex (i.e. *treatable*) approximation of the problem. Introduce the matrix $X=xx^T$.

1. Rewrite the conditions $x^TA_kx=0$ equivalently as $\text{tr}\,A_k X=0$.
2. Add normalization $\text{tr}\,X=1$ to avoid the trivial solution.
3. Minimize rank of $X$.

Clearly, if there is a vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^4\setminus\{0\}$ that solves the original problem then the rank minimization gives you a rank one matrix, and you can easily find $x$ via factorization of the optimal $X$. Otherwise, if the optimal rank is two or more, then there is no solution to the original problem.

Rank minimization is quite hard (not convex), but there are numerous convex relaxations to it, e.g. using the nuclear norm. The nuclear norm is simply a sum of all singular values $\|X\|_*=\sum_{k=1}^N\sigma_k(X)$, and the minimal solution [is known to be of very low rank](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~brecht/papers/07.rfp.lowrank.pdf) in general. So a possible relaxation of the problem is the norm minimization with linear constraints
$$
\min_{X}\|X\|_*\qquad\text{subject to}\quad \text{tr}\,X=1,\ \text{tr}\,A_k X=0,\  k=1,...,4.
$$

UPDATE: You can also test your matrices first by a necessary condition for existence of a non-trivial solution. Obviously, there is no such solution *if* there exist $\tau_k\in\mathbb{R}$ such that the matrix $\sum_{k=1}^4\tau_kA_k$ is positive definite. Looking for $\tau_k$ is a [semi-definite programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidefinite_programming) that can be solved efficiently.

Comment: Can you explain why the equations in 1. are equivalent ?

Comment: @GrigoryIlizirov $x^TAx$ is a scalar, so $x^TAx=\text{tr}(x^TAx)$. Now we use the rule that $\text{tr}(BC)=\text{tr}(CB)$. Here take, for example, $x^T$ as $B$ to get $\text{tr}(x^TAx)=\text{tr}(Axx^T)=\text{tr}(AX)$.

Comment: This is interesting, but I am already solved this problem by nonlinear least squares which is more simple and faster then your approach. Anyway now i am looking for analytical solution.

Answer (score 1):

Writing the example as
$$ \eqalign{a^2 + b^2 + c - \dfrac{395}{100} &= 0\cr a b + b c + c^2 - \dfrac{457}{100} &= 0\cr a c+b-\dfrac{263}{100} &= 0\cr}$$
and using Maple, I get the rational solution
$$ a = \dfrac{11}{10},\ b = \dfrac{6}{5},\ c = \dfrac{13}{10} $$
as well as the more complicated
 $$  \eqalign{ a = &-{\frac {571155568\,{r}^{6}}{239293241139037}}-{\frac {
97836027296\,{r}^{5}}{5982331028475925}}+{\frac {6231586801884\,{r}^{4
}}{5982331028475925}}+{\frac {23593267878176\,{r}^{3}}{
5982331028475925}}\cr &-{\frac {1202499156203509\,{r}^{2}}{5982331028475925
}}+{\frac {5383059078675992\,r}{5982331028475925}}+{\frac {
34070673499587139}{11964662056951850}}\cr b  = & r/5\cr c = &-{\frac {4414166864\,{r
}^{6}}{1196466205695185}}-{\frac {224758604064\,{r}^{5}}{
5982331028475925}}+{\frac {8175883963396\,{r}^{4}}{5982331028475925}}+
{\frac {58329732068364\,{r}^{3}}{5982331028475925}}\cr &  -{\frac {
1516933817840111\,{r}^{2}}{5982331028475925}}+{\frac {4604325789069518
\,r}{5982331028475925}}+{\frac {46730409611551821}{11964662056951850}}
 } 
$$
where $r$ is a root of the irreducible septic
$$ 16\,{r}^{7}+176\,{r}^{6}-6188\,{r}^{5}-54928\,{r}^{4}+1095565\,{r}^{3}
-1042350\,{r}^{2}-25308581\,r-29724296
$$
This has three real roots, approximately $-3.258533342, -1.369218643, 14.03972857$.  Its Galois group is $S_7$, so no solutions in radicals.

Comment: Thank you @Robert, but I am looking for analytical method to find this values....

Comment: The analytic method is to find a Groebner basis, using Buchberger's algorithm or one of its more recent variants.

Comment: @RobertIsrael which anyway requires finding roots of a univariate polynomial

Comment: ... or rather expresses the answers in terms of the roots of a univariate polynomial.  I don't expect there to be any "analytical method" that does better than that: when the coefficients are rational and the solution set is finite, the answers are algebraic numbers, in general not rational and not expressible by radicals (as in the example).  How else are you going to specify them?

Answer (score 0):

Four equations, but since they are homogeneous there are just three degrees of freedom (say on the unit sphere).  So you'll have to be lucky to get any nontrivial solutions at all.  Try solving three of these together with $x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + x_4^2 = 1$, and then seeing if the solutions satisfy the fourth equation.

Comment: But you will always have the solution $x=0$, don't you?

Comment: OK, any **nontrivial** solutions.

Comment: Yes i am looking for nontrivial homogeneous solutions. Can rewrite the proplem with $y=Ux$ to make one of the matrix diagonal... one of the equation becomes: $a_1y^2_1+a_2y^2_2+a_3y^2_3+a_4y^2_4=0$. But that doesn't help to solve

Comment: You can also rescale so $a_1, \ldots a_4$ all have absolute value $1$.  There are two nontrivial cases: $y_1^2 + y_2^2 = y_3^2 + y_4^2$ and $y_1^2 = y_2^2 + y_3^2 + y_4^2$.

Comment: Hm, well, $1$ or $0$.  So there are also the cases $y_1^2 = y_2^2 + y_3^2$ and $y_1^2 = y_2^2$.

Answer (score 0):

@ Grigory Ilizirov , you spend your money my friend! Indeed, Robert gave (10 monthes ago !) a three lines solution that clearly shows that your problem has no non-zero solutions when the $(A_i)_i$ are generic matrices.

More precisely, consider the system (S) $x^TA_1x=x^TA_2x=x^TA_3x=x^Tx-1=0$. If $x$ is a solution of (S), then a vector $h$ of the tangent space in $x$ of the set of all solutions satisfies: $h^TA_1x=h^TA_2x=h^TA_3x=h^Tx=0$. Then $h$ is orthogonal to the $3$ vectors $A_1x,A_2x,A_3x$ which, in the generic case, generate a vector space of dimension $3$. then $h$ and $x$ are parallel vectors. Finally, the condition $h^Tx=0$ implies that $h=0$; we conclude that $x$ is an isolated solution and cannot, in the generic case, satisfies the last equation $x^TA_4x=0$ (otherwise $A_4$ would depend on $x$).

EDIT. There are no general formulae. Yet, if you know explicitly the matrice $(A_i)$, as in your example above, you can formally solve the system (S) $x^TA_1x=x^TA_2x=x^TA_3x=x^Tx-1=0$, using the Grobner basis theory (the software is included in Maple). You obtain all $16$ complex solutions in the form $P_{16}(x_1)=0,$for every $i>1, x_i=Q_i(x_1)$, where $P_{16}$ is an even polynomial of degree $16$ and the $(Q_i)$ are polynomial of degree $15$. It remains to keep the real solutions. You may assume $x_1>0$; then there are between $0$ and $8$ real solutions. Of course the effective calculation of the $(x_i)$ is impossible because $P_{16}$ is not solvable by radicals.

Comment: I suppose it is not a "generic case", because I know that not trivial solution is exists for my matrices.