# Solving systems of quadratic equations

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, systems-of-equations, quadratics, tensors

There are [efficient algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Solving_a_linear_system) for solving a system of linear equations of the form

$$\forall i \qquad 0 = a^i + \sum_j b^i_j x^j$$

or

$$\mathbf{0} = \mathbf{a} + \mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{x}$$

Are there efficient algorithms for solving a system of quadratic equations of the form

$$\forall i \qquad 0 = a^i + \sum_j b^i_j x^j + \sum_k \sum_j c^i_{jk} x^j x^k$$

or

$$\mathbf{0} = \mathbf{a} + \mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{c} \cdot \mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{x}$$

and if so, what are they?

Comment: Calculating the Groebner basis is one way to do it.

Comment: @Chrystomath Can you expand on that a little bit?

Comment: You need to specify whether the coefficients are integer or real, and whether you would require exact solutions or just approximations.

Comment: @Chrystomath The coefficients are real. An exact solution is desired, if possible.

Comment: Define "solve".  In the two variable case, the solution sets are ellipses, parabolas, hyperbolas, two parallel lines, two intersecting lines, a double line, or a point.  In three variables, these are ellipsoids, hyperboloids, paraboloids, variations of those, and a zoo of degenerate cases.  Solution sets are not as simple as in the linear case; sometimes these equations are the compact solution set description.  So what does "solve" mean?

Comment: @EricTowers Good question. Any solution (if one exists) suffices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As shown by [Robert Israel](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8508/robert-israel)'s [answer to a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1397331/123905), particular instances of this problem scheme need not have solutions which are simply expressed (unlike the linear case, where the solution is always expressible as finite expressions in the given coefficients, in the quadratic and higher degree cases, the solution may need roots of high degree polynomials, for which there need not be any expression in the original coefficients).  So the best we can hope for is a method similar to elimination which trades fewer variables for higher degrees.  [Groebner basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis) calculations are such a method.

One might wish that the degree 2 bound in the inputs could allow a nicer solution, [but no](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2947650/groebner-basis-calculation-for-degree-2-polynomials): a degree 2 bounded solution algorithm is actually an algorithm for a system with unconstrained degrees.

There are several [Groebner basis implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis#Implementations).  I do not recommend attempting this technique by hand except for carefully constructed exercises (for which, see books, like Cox, Little, and O'Shea, *Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms: An Introduction to Computational Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra*).

Comment: Regarding the first point: an arbitrary polynomial can be encoded in a system of quadratic equations. For example, the system
$$\begin{cases}
x_2 = x_1^2 \\
x_3 = x_1 x_2 \\
x_4 = x_1 x_3 \\
x_5 = x_1 x_4 \\
x_5 - x_1 + 1 = 0
\end{cases}$$
is equivalent to the quintic equation $x^5 - x + 1= 0$.

Comment: What’s the time complexity of this approach?

Comment: @user76284 : Let $d$ be the maximum total degree of the input polynomials and $n$ the number of variables.  Then the current best proved complexity is $d^{2^{n+o(1)}}$ and there are problem instances of complexity $d^{2^{\Omega(n)}}$, so the complexity cannot be significantly reduced.  Since your polynomials have maximum total degree $2$, this is $2^{2^{n+o(1)}}$.

Comment: @EricTowers That's tough. Do you think a [root-finding algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm) might work better in practice?

Comment: @user76284 : Absolutely, yes.